# JSON error when using Retrofit with HTML

Tags: php, android, html, json, retrofit

My code works fine when I remove HTML code from index.php and just keep the php lines between . But when I use the as shown down with HTML lines - which I need for other parts of the application -, it gives error:

"Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $"

I have tried to use

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
```

But it gives me another error:

"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

This is my [Logcat output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j110m.png)

How to fix that?!!!

FirstPOIPreference.java:

```
public class FirstPOIPreference extends DialogPreference {

private EditText et_alias, et_keyword, et_address;
private Spinner sp_city;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private boolean deleted;
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private POI poiDialog = new POI();

public FirstPOIPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
    init();
}

private void init() {
    setPersistent(false);
    setDialogLayoutResource(R.layout.pref_poi_dialog);
    setPositiveButtonText(android.R.string.ok);
    setNegativeButtonText(android.R.string.cancel);
}

@Override
protected void onBindDialogView(View view) {
    super.onBindDialogView(view);
    pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.context);
    load(getSharedPreferences());
    initViews(view);
    fillViews();
}

private void load(SharedPreferences prefs) {
    poiDialog.setAlias(prefs.getString(Constants.FIRST_POI_ALIAS, ""));
    poiDialog.setKeyword(prefs.getString(Constants.FIRST_POI_KEYWORD, ""));
    poiDialog.setAddress(prefs.getString(Constants.FIRST_POI_ADDRESS, ""));
    poiDialog.setCity((prefs.getString(Constants.FIRST_POI_CITY, "")));
}

private void initViews(View view) {
    deleted = false;
    TextView tv_delete = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_poi_delete);
    et_alias = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_poi_alias);
    et_keyword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_poi_keyword);
    et_address = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_poi_address);
    sp_city = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_poi_city);
    sp_city.setPrompt("City");
    String[] arrayCity = new String[]{"Erie", "Pittsburgh", "Cleveland", "Buffalo", "Niagara Falls", "Jamestown"};
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter <> (this.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arrayCity);
    sp_city.setAdapter(adapter);

    et_alias.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            poiDialog.setAlias(et_alias.getText().toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    et_keyword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            poiDialog.setKeyword(et_keyword.getText().toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    et_address.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            poiDialog.setAddress(et_address.getText().toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
    });

    sp_city.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <?> parentView, View selectedItemView,
                                   int position, long id) {
            poiDialog.setCity(sp_city.getSelectedItem().toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <?> parentView) {
        }
    });

    tv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder delete_builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            delete_builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this point of interest?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Deleting POI !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            deletePOI();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDelete = delete_builder.create();
            alertDelete.setTitle("Delete POI!");
            alertDelete.show();
        }
    });
}

private void fillViews() {
    et_alias.setText(poiDialog.getAlias());
    et_keyword.setText(poiDialog.getKeyword());
    et_address.setText(poiDialog.getAddress());
    sp_city.setSelection(adapter.getPosition(poiDialog.getCity()));
}

@Override
protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult) {
    if (positiveResult) {
        String alias, keyword, address, city;
        if(deleted) {
            et_alias.setText("");
            et_keyword.setText("");
            et_address.setText("");
            sp_city.setPrompt("City");
        } else {
            alias = et_alias.getText().toString();
            keyword = et_keyword.getText().toString();
            address = et_address.getText().toString();
            city = sp_city.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (!keyword.isEmpty() && !address.isEmpty() && !city.isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Saving POI !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                addPOI(alias, keyword, address, city);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Required Fields are empty !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void addPOI(String alias, String keyword, String address, String city) {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(interceptor)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(pref.getString(Constants.USER_EMAIL, ""));

    POI poi = new POI();
    poi.setAlias(alias);
    poi.setKeyword(keyword);
    poi.setAddress(address);
    poi.setCity(city);

    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.ADD_POI);
    request.setUser(user);
    request.setPoi(poi);

    Call <ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);
    response.enqueue(new Callback <ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call <ServerResponse> call,
                               retrofit2.Response <ServerResponse> response) {
            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
                save(editor);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call <ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "failed");
            Toast.makeText(context, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void save(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_ALIAS, poiDialog.getAlias());
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_KEYWORD, poiDialog.getKeyword());
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_ADDRESS, poiDialog.getAddress());
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_CITY, poiDialog.getCity());
    editor.apply();
}

private void deletePOI() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    User user = new User();
    user.setEmail(pref.getString(Constants.USER_EMAIL, ""));

    POI poi = new POI();
    poi.setKeyword(pref.getString(Constants.FIRST_POI_KEYWORD, ""));
    poi.setCity(pref.getString(Constants.FIRST_POI_CITY, ""));

    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.DELETE_POI);
    request.setUser(user);
    request.setPoi(poi);

    Call <ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);
    response.enqueue(new Callback <ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call <ServerResponse> call,
                               retrofit2.Response <ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getEditor();
                saveDelete(editor);
                deleted = true;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, resp.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call <ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(Constants.TAG, "failed");
            Toast.makeText(context, t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

private void saveDelete(SharedPreferences.Editor editor) {
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_ALIAS, "");
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_KEYWORD, "");
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_ADDRESS, "");
    editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_POI_CITY, "");
    editor.apply();
}

}
```

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <?php

        // dispaly all errors except Warnings
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);

        include 'fetch_data.php';
        require_once 'users/login.php';
        require_once 'preferences/preferences.php';
        require_once 'include/functions_validation.php';

        $login = new Login();
        $pref = new Preferences();
        $fun = new FunctionsValidation();

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

            if(isset($data -> operation)) {
                $operation = $data -> operation;
                if(!empty($operation)) {
                    /*
                    * User registration and login operations
                    */
                    if($operation == 'register') {
                        echo $login -> register($data);
                    }
                    else if ($operation == 'regVerify') {
                        echo $login -> registerVerify($data);
                    }
                    else if ($operation == 'login') {
                        echo $login -> login($data);
                    }
                    else if ($operation == 'chgPass') {
                        echo $login -> changePassword($data);
                    }
                    else if ($operation == 'resPassReq') {
                        echo $login -> resetPasswordReq($data);
                    }
                    else if ($operation == 'resPass') {
                        echo $login -> resetPassword($data);
                    }
                    /*
                     * Point of Interest operations
                     */
                    else if($operation == 'addPOI') {
                        echo $pref -> addPOI($data);
                    }
                    else if($operation == 'deletePOI') {
                        echo $pref -> deletePOI($data);
                    }

                    /**
                     * Mileage Distance operations
                     */
                    else if($operation == 'addMileage') {
                        echo $pref -> addMileage($data);
                    }
                    else if($operation == 'deleteMileage') {
                        echo $pref -> deleteMileage($data);
                    }
                } else { // if operation is empty
                    echo $fun -> getMsgParamNotEmpty();
                }
            } else { // if operation is not set
                echo $fun -> getMsgInvalidParam();
            }
        } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
            echo "GeolocationNews API";
        }
        ?>
      </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `Constants.BASE_URL` point to your `index.php` page?

If so, you're trying to parse a HTML page as JSON, which is invalid. I suggest you send some kind of query parameter from your Android app that you can check for from PHP, so that the HTML portions aren't included in the output.

Let's say your Android app submits the request to `index.php?output=json` for example. Then in your index.php you can check for that:

```
<?php
$jsonOnly = (isset($_GET['output']) && $_GET['output'] == 'json');

if (!$jsonOnly):
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
<?php
endif;

// your existing PHP code here

if (!$jsonOnly):
?>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
<?php
endif;
?>
```

**Edit** However, I think it would be better to separate your logic from your presentation. What if you were to put all your PHP code in a separate file, e.g. `handle_request.php`? Then in your index.php, you can have all your HTML code and then include that file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <pre>
        <?php include('handle_request.php'); ?>
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

For your app, you can then create a different file that you use as your `Constants.BASE_URL`, say `app.php`, which only sets up a proper JSON content-type header and includes the same file:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
include('handle_request.php');
?>
```

Comment: Yes, the BASE_URL points to index.php. I have done what you said in my index.php, but I do not know how to send the parameter. I have edited my question and post an image of Logcat output, it is like what you said.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using Retrofit, but from what Google tells me there's usually an interface where you define your API endpoints. There, you can use the @Query() annotation to send a query parameter (simply adding it to your base url won't work).

Although I think you're making life very hard on yourself by having this code accessible from two locations, where one requires JSON and the other HTML. In my opinion, it would be better to separate logic from presentation, so I'm going to update my answer.